# Java Junit test case fails as it gets expected value type of String and actual value type of ArrayList

Tags: java, junit, types, assert, assertion

I am writing a Junit test case and the test case fails due to the mismatch in type. When I see the difference I see that the expected value is in `String` and the Actual value is `ArrayList` but the rest of everything is the same. Is there any way to compare only the content and not the type?

Following is the code that I have:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void SimpleTest() throws Exception {
        final List<String> actualList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        actualList.add("{ \"name\": \"Hello\",\"job\": \"Zimmermann\"}");
        actualList.add("{ \"name\": \"Bye\",\"job\": \"Malen\"}");

        final String expectedJson = new String(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./expected.json").readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println(expectedJson);
        System.out.println(actualList);

        assertEquals(expectedJson, actualList);
    }
}
```

My expected.json:

```
[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]
```

Output:

```
[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]
[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]

java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.String<[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]>
Expected :java.lang.String<[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]>
Actual   :java.util.ArrayList<[{ "name": "Hello","job": "Zimmermann"}, { "name": "Bye","job": "Malen"}]>
<Click to see difference>
```

When I see the difference the only difference is that: expected is String and actual is ArrayList. So I tried converting the expected to `ArrayList` but that's adding one more `Array` due to which content is wrapped in multiple Array.

Is there any way I can try to check only for content and ignore the data type in Junit or is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: `actualList` is a list of Strings and not a json

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot for the resposne. Yes, it is a List of String but when I am comparing the error is not due to a mismatch with JSON but rather due to `String` and `ArrayList`. So I am wondering if there is a way to compare only the content rather than the datatype as well. So I can compare only the data and see if they are equal.

Comment: I see two ways, converting both to json or write an own function, that do the compare for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer as it can be useful to someone else in the future:

To fix the issue I tried to convert both actual and expected output into JsonNode using the `ObjectMapper` of the `Fasterxml Jackson` library.

Following is the same code for the same:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MyTest {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void SimpleTest() throws Exception {
        final List<String> actualList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        actualList.add("{ \"name\": \"Hello\",\"job\": \"Zimmermann\"}");
        actualList.add("{ \"name\": \"Bye\",\"job\": \"Malen\"}");

        final String expectedJson = new String(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./expected.json").readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println(expectedJson);
        System.out.println(actualList);

        //assertEquals(expectedJson, actualList);
        assertEquals(objectMapper.readTree(expectedJson), objectMapper.readTree(actualList.toString()));
    }
}
```